# pseudo css .hover explanation

Tags: css

im trying to construct my own navigation bar, Ive seen some forum with (css), and then im stuck of this css line,

```
 #navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul {
```

i know that the `#navbar` is the id name,`#navbar li:hover ul` i think this code said when you hover the mouse in `li` the `ul` change and became like this:`display: block;position: absolute;margin: 0;padding: 0;`. this one is my problem? `#navbar li.hover ul` whats the meaning of this, then what about on dot(.) before the hover? can some one explain this line `, #navbar li.hover ul`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Answer (score 2):

I could guess that the rule `#navbar li.hover ul` was defined for `IE6`(and previous).

Since that browser doesn't support `:hover` pseudoclass for elements different than links, probably there is some javascript defined for that browser that is toggling the `.hover` class on `mouseover/mouseenter` event.

Answer (score 1):

```
#navbar li:hover ul
```

this one means: "the UL inside a hovered LI inside something with ID navbar."

```
#navbar li.hover ul
```

this one means: " the UL inside a LI having class 'hover', inside something with ID navbar."

The comma between them means that the following CSS rules apply to both cases.

Answer (score 0):

the "dot" means that it is the class of the li.